# Closing the Find box in VSCode doesn't stop highlighting the matched words

Tags: visual-studio-code

I press ctrl+f and the Find box appears. I type in "thing" and it matches stuff in the file I'm looking at. I then press Escape and the Find box disappears.
But it's still highlighting the matching "thing"s in my file.
Is this a setting somewhere ?

I have recently added the "Sublime Text Key map and Settings Importer" extension, but can't see where in there this would be caused.

I've run "Check for Updates" in VS Code as well.

Does anyone else have this problem?
Cheers

Comment: That doesn't happen to me.  If you have one of the old matches otherwise selected you will still get a highlight on all matches regardless if the Find Panel is open  or not.

Comment: Any idea what the setting might be for this ?  I don't select any match, close Find box, and they all stay highlighted.   
I haven't a clue what I could have changed.

Comment: It's something to do with the Sublime Text Keymap extension.

Comment: Not really related to Sublime. I have never used that extension and I am having the same issue. It really seems to be a setting because usually I dont have that issue, but from time to time I do.

Reloading vscode doesnt help. So unless I "unset" whatever is causing that I guess Ill be annoyed.